# How to find a string match ( both partial and exact match) between column header and row values in python using if condition

Tags: python, pandas, string, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
id  references  apple  pomegranate
a234    papaya      0      1
b231    pomegranate 1      0
a234    apple       0      1
g34     mango       0      0
y34     strawberry  0      1
```

Is there a way to match column name "apple" with names in "references" column, so that I could extract the corresponding "id"....considering the data frame as say a distance value of two data frames about  features of fruits.

The match is searched for exact string match in first iteration if it's not found, partial match also searched, say some "references" value may have a name "green apple". So it is partial match this case is considered when exact match is unavailable.

Comment: Not sure what your end goal here is but you can treat the column header as a list and then search for the elements. Searching for a list of values in pandas column should be available on stackoverflow already.

Comment: Is your example correct? Why is there a 1 in column "pomegranate" when the references are "papaya", "apple" and "strawberry"?

Comment: @not_speshal yes correct,  since pomegranate is not related to those three fruits the distance is 1, when the relationship is closer distance is 0

Comment: How do you define "relationship"?

Comment: @not_speshal It is any distance measure, say Euclidean /Manhattan etc for that matter. It establishes a relationship between two entities, two types of apples, red apple and green apple are more closer to the fruit apple than mango...

Comment: How *exactly* do you define Manhattan and Euclidean distances for strings? For example, what is the "distance" between "apple" and "elephant"? Is "apple" farther from "elephant" than "india"? You need to be much more specific if you want the correct code

Comment: Yes that is what i mentioned in the question, the features about fruits(colour, size, family, etc.,) indicated as numbers. say i have 9 such parameters for all fruits...then i calculate euclidean distance, and 0s and 1s indicate euclidean distance rounded, and now i need to find a match between two similar fruits as thier distance is 0 and get their 'id'